# Converting square metres to Square Kilometres using javax.measure

Tags: java, units-of-measurement

I have a program that calculates the area of a polygon in metres squared and I would like to convert it to other units (as the user wants) using the [`javax.measure`](http://jscience.org/api/javax/measure/package-summary.html) library.

```
Measure<Double, Area> a = Measure.valueOf(area, SI.SQUARE_METRE);
```

So if I want hectares I can use:

```
a.doubleValue(NonSI.HECTARE);
```

but the only other `Area` quantity is `Are`.

While I can easily divide through by 1000*1000 to get KM squared it gets messier when I try to get Acres or Sq Miles or other common areal units.

Comment: 1mi² = 2.59km² (so 10mi² = 25.9km² and so on), you may just multiply ;)

Comment: I know I can do it by multiplication but I was hoping for a Units based solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation and experimentation I can generate sq miles and sq kilometres as so:

```
Unit<Area> sq_km = (Unit<Area>) SI.KILOMETER.times(SI.KILOMETER);
System.out.println(a.to(sq_km));
Unit<Area> sq_mile = (Unit<Area>) NonSI.MILE.times(NonSI.MILE);
System.out.println(a.to(sq_mile));
System.out.println(a.to(NonSI.HECTARE));
```

Which gives me the output:

```
4.872007325925411E11 m²
487200.7325925411 km²
188109.25449744106 mi²
4.8720073259254105E7 ha
```

But acres are escaping me, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acre) an acre is 1 furlong times 66 ft. So I tried:

```
Unit<Area> acre = (Unit<Area>) NonSI.MILE.divide(8.0).times(NonSI.FOOT).times(66.0);
System.out.println(a.to(acre));
```

which gives the right answer but gives me a unit of `m²*4046.8564224`.

**Edit**

So further experimentation gives me:

```
Unit<Area> acre = (Unit<Area>) NonSI.MILE.divide(8.0).times(NonSI.FOOT).times(66.0);
UnitFormat.getInstance().label(acre, "acre");
```

and the output (for a different polygon than before):

```
2.6529660563942477E7 acre
```

**Further Update**

[GeoTools](https://geotools.org) now uses [JSR-363](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/welcome/upgrade.html#migrate-to-jsr-363-units) units so the above becomes:

```
Unit<Area> sq_km = (Unit<Area>) MetricPrefix.KILO(SI.METRE).multiply(MetricPrefix.KILO(SI.METRE));
System.out.println(a.to(sq_km));
System.out.println(pop.divide(a.to(sq_km)));

Unit<Area> sq_mile = (Unit<Area>) USCustomary.MILE.multiply(USCustomary.MILE);
System.out.println(a.to(sq_mile));
System.out.println(a.to(NonSI.HECTARE));

System.out.println(a.to(USCustomary.ACRE).getValue() + " acres");
```

So Acres are in but for some reason don't have a unit defined in the java8 jar (but does in [master](https://github.com/unitsofmeasurement/uom-systems/blob/master/common/src/main/java/systems/uom/common/USCustomary.java#L280)).

Comment: ACRE has been in the java8 variant of systems-common for about 2 years now: https://github.com/unitsofmeasurement/uom-systems/blob/master/common-java8/src/main/java/systems/uom/common/USCustomary.java

Answer (score 1):

A code snippet like `NonSI.MILE.divide(8.0).times...` tells you are using the old, unfinished JSR 275 and implementations like JScience 4 in your solution.

Any reason to prefer that over the official, finished javax.measure [JSR 363](http://unitsofmeasurement.github.io/)?

All of above with a few variations (e.g. UnitFormat is an API interface now, the code in JSR 363 would be `SimpleUnitFormat.getInstance().label(acre, "acre");`) works perfectly fine in JSR 363. Unlike 275 there is also a vast infrastructure of extension modules for the SI System and other Unit systems. And a couple of major Open Source projects already use the new standard. Give it a try.

Comment: is JSR363 a drop in replacement for JSR 275 or would we (http://geotools.org) need to make a bunch of changes?

Comment: I assume you work with Martin on GeoTools? The package structure changes slightly to make JSR 363 more modular than 275, but key elements like **Unit**, **Dimension** or **Quantity** have nearly identical methods and behavior. The built-in quantity types like **Length** are even more similar, there it's often a drop-in replacement. Let us know, if you have problems or ask Martin. Regards, Werner